# Slick Slider show only 1 item in center, display overflow to left and right

Tags: css, slick.js

I'm trying to make a slider using Slick Slider that will show the "slider" in the center of the container with a width of 50%. I want the remaining 50% to display on either side. I want the arrows to appear in the center.

I'm trying to achieve this effect:
[image: desired result]

When I set the width of the container to 50%, and I apply this css in developer tools, I get the desired result:

```
.slick-list { overflow: visible; }
```

But as soon as I scroll, something resets and the overflow disappears.

Comment: ...and? What happens when you try to achieve this effect?

Comment: Please post some related code in here, of  what you have tried so far, or please elaborate on issue you are facing for the same.

Comment: When I set the width of .carousel-container to 50% with margin:0 auto (center), the items that overflow are hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking a different approach. Instead of limiting the width of the container, I found this setting `variableWidth: true` that made the `slidesToShow: 1` setting use the extra white space. From there, I used this CSS to position the prev/next arrows relative to the width of the container:

```
 .carousel-container .slick-next {
    right: calc((100vw - 630px)/2)
  }

  .carousel-container .slick-prev {
    left: calc((100vw - 630px)/2)
  }
```

This works because each of slides are the same width (variableWidth property was misleading for this reason).

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
.slick-slider {
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

.slick-prev {
    margin-left: 25%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.slick-next {
    margin-right: 25%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You need to make sure your css rules override existing ones set by the Slick carousel, so you'll probably need to be more specific in your css selectors, but try not to use `!important` everywhere. You could maybe prepend the css classes here with the css class of your carousel container.

Comment: I've tried positioning the arrows with the technique you mention here, but it needs to be adjusted for smaller screen sizes. When I apply this CSS, the arrows are in the right place, but each element in the carousel is aligned to the left (the center is empty space)

Comment: It's worth reading this to ask a better question: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)